# How to transfer ETH using signature

Tags: signature

I've browsing and interacting with ZKSync ,which i came across sign a signature [image: You can see]

I was curious to know how i can create a function like transfer ETH or possibly ERC20 token using signature, i know there is a string in each signature which is message called usually, and I think in this message we should enter what we want to do, but I don't know how?

Anyone can write a function that can call a function like the image??
Thanks